# :id=> nil missing required keys :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I am creating a new app with simple authentication, but i get this error:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil}, 
>        missing 
>       required keys: [:id]

I have tried other stackoverflow solutions but none have seemed to work for me.

This is my users_controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new; end

  def create
    @user = User.create(password: params[:password], email: params[:email], 
firstname: params[:firstname], lastname: params[:lastname])
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

My sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      def new
      end
      def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Email or password is invalid"
      render "new"
    end
  end
  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = 1 
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged out!"
  end
   end
```

routes.rb :

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
   # Fubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root :to => 'static#welcome'
  resources :users, only: [:new, :create, :show]
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :studios
end

<h1> Hey, <%= @user.firstname %>! </h1>
<h3><a href="http://localhost:3000">Home</a></h3> 
<%= link_to "Log Out", session_path, method: :delete %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'users', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => 
true %>
```

Comment: Can you post the call in the view where you have the path for show, like user_path(@user) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your user_show route it would be like

```
users/:id/show
```

You have to pass param id along with your request to show that id object. Right now you're call is missing param id.

You're call should be like this

```
users/1/show
```

Where as 1 is the user id in DB

Answer (score 1):

The problem is after create a user? If yes, make sure that the user is being created and exists. The problem could be that `@user` is nil